# How to return an iterator from a function including the end case

Tags: c++, c++11

In c++ I need to search a vector containing a pair, in reverse, by the string. I cannot use a map because the strings are not unique and order is important. I then want to return a forward iterator if the string is found or the end iterator if the string is not found.

Please see below for my current code. I have no problem when the string is found but, if the string is not found, I get a segfault in the conditional statement in main.

```
vector<pair<string, int>>::iterator prev_it(const string& pred, 
        vector<pair<string, int>> prevpreds) {
    vector<pair<string, int>>::reverse_iterator rit;
    for(rit = prevpreds.rbegin(); 
            rit != prevpreds.rend(); ++rit) {
        if (rit->first == pred) {
            return (rit+1).base();}
    }
    if(rit == prevpreds.rend()) {
        return prevpreds.end();
    }
}
```

and in main:

```
int main() {
    vector<pair<string, int>> test;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
        pair<string, int> mypair;
        mypair = make_pair("X"+to_string(i%4+1), i+1);
        test.emplace_back(mypair);
    }
    string tpred = "X"+to_string(6);

    vector<pair<string, int>>::iterator tit;
    tit = prev_it(tpred, test);

    if (tit != test.end()) {
        cout << tit->first << " " << tit->second << endl;
    }
    else {cout << "This is the end." << endl;}
}
```

The code works if tpred is one of X1 to X4. If tpred is X6 (i.e. not an element of test) then I get a segfault. What I would like to be able to do is return the end forward iterator and then, as in main(), have a conditional based on this.

Edit: I am new to c++ (about a year). I am returning a forward iterator because I need to use the iterator later and this seems clearer (but I could be wrong). As far as I understand, a multimap allows non-unique keys but will order the unique keys. I should have been clearer and said time order was important, not key order. I prefer not to use auto while developing because I like to see what I container element/iterator I am using, but point taken.

Comment: Why do you search in reverse and then return a forward iterator?

Comment: Instead of `vector<pair<string, int>>`, a [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) might be more suitable/readable here.

Comment: and use `auto` to shorten those iterator variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an iterator of a destructed object. Pass `prevpreds` by reference, so the iterator maintains valid.

```
vector<pair<string, int>>::const_iterator prev_it(const string& pred,
                                        const vector<pair<string, int>> &prevpreds)
{
    vector<pair<string, int>>::const_reverse_iterator rit;
    for (rit = prevpreds.rbegin();
            rit != prevpreds.rend(); ++rit)
    {
        if (rit->first == pred)
        {
            return (rit + 1).base();
        }
    }

    return prevpreds.end();
}

int main()
{
    // ...

    vector<pair<string, int>>::const_iterator tit; // <-- uses const iterator
    tit = prev_it(tpred, test);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think this: `return rit.base(); // <-- I think this should be here` is not needed and `return prevpreds.end();` should be without the `if` statement.

Comment: @DimChtz: Edited.